# Satis for Python

Tags: python, pypi, satis, devpi

Is there anything like Satis from PHP for Python?
I've tried some tools for "private pypi's" respectively private package indexes like devpi or pyshop.
I want to mirror some packages which are also needed offline, but I don't want to mirror the whole pypi (more like a caching proxy).
And I want to upload privately developed packages.
Also it would be really useful if it automatically caches the dependencies of my uploaded packages or if I can give it a file containing all needed packages (like satis build) with the source (e.g. pypi, vcs/svn) and it caches / adds them to the index.

I'm searching for a option to make a private package index but devpi has not all the features I need.

Comment: Something like this: https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#usage ?

Comment: Are you looking for [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/quickstart-pypimirror.html)?

Comment: the closest option would be infact devpi... maybe with a plugin in the future